# asyncio.create_task with function decorator

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I want these code blocks works as predicted, is there any suggestions?

```
def task(func: Any):

    @wraps(func)
    async def wrapped(*args: Any) -> Task[Any]:
        return create_task(func(*args))

    return wrapped

# Create task without using create_task method
@task
async def printe_task():
    await sleep(1)
    print("Hello")


async def printer():
    await sleep(1)
    print("Hello")

task = create_task(printer())
await task

# This method should be same as above!
await printer_task()  # <--------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Ups, I just need to make wrapper sync instead of async ‍♂️

```py
def task(func: Any):

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args: Any) -> Task[Any]:  # <--- async keyword removed!
        return create_task(func(*args))

    return wrapped

# Create task without using create_task method
@task
async def printe_task():
    await sleep(1)
    print("Hello")


async def printer():
    await sleep(1)
    print("Hello")

task = create_task(printer())
await task

# This method should be same as above!
await printer_task()  # <--------------
```